# Serve two files with the same name, but different content

Tags: nginx, directory, subdomain

Situation: i have two files with the same name "My_file", but with diferent content. I would like to read\download "My_File" from test.com/My-File with one content, and from 1.test.com/My_File with another content.

Is there any possible config in nginx to do this? I guess it's configurable through if statements.

Comment: You have two different domains. Use two different `server` blocks.

Comment: Thx Alexey! Just created another server and configered location and root for it.